# php .htaccess not redirecting properly

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

```
Redirect 301 /aboutus.html  http://www.somedomain.co.uk/about-us/
Redirect 301 /brochuredownloads.php?file=Wessex_Sectional_Brochure.pdf http://www.somedomain.co.uk/brochure-downloads/
```

I was developing one core php site now that site change to wordpress. So some link I am getting 404 page. So I want to redirect that.

Above is my .htaccess redirect code. 1st line working fine. But second line not working. can you please say me why not redirect properly?

Also I tried many ways -

```
Redirect 301 "/brochuredownloads.php?file=Wessex_Sectional_Brochure.pdf" http://www.somedomain.co.uk/brochure-downloads/
Redirect 301 ^brochuredownloads.php?file=Wessex_Sectional_Brochure.pdf$ http://www.somedomain.co.uk/brochure-downloads/
Redirect 301 brochuredownloads.php\?file=Wessex_Sectional_Brochure.pdf http://www.somedomain.co.uk/brochure-downloads/
```

These are not working

Comment: Can you try this `Redirect 301 /brochuredownloads.php http://www.somedomain.co.uk/brochure-downloads/`

Comment: No I want to redirect from particular link which I have mentioned.

Comment: @Chinu have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: @123 yes I have cleared my browser cache

Answer (score 1):

mod_alias doesn't support query string matching (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html), you'll have to use mod_rewrite, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  "brochuredownloads\.php\?file=Wessex_Sectional_Brochure\.pdf"
RewriteRule . http://www.somedomain.co.uk/brochure-downloads/  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It works for me. What exactly do you mean by not working? What is happening? Tail the apache error log when you run it.

Comment: Ok, Again I will try.